# How can I run a specific example using PEST (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, testing, php-pest, pestphp

Now I use `./vendor/bin/pest` as explained in the [docs](https://pestphp.com/docs/installation). But that makes me run all tests. What if I only want to run one specific example? Do I need to use [groups](https://pestphp.com/docs/groups) or can it be done in an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering of tests isn’t part of the Pest framework, instead that is handled by the underlying test runner. This is most commonly PHPUnit and you can find a list of the [CLI options in their docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html#command-line-options).

Answer (score 0):

Append `->only()` to the end of the test to run:

```php
test('sum', function () {
  $result = sum(1, 2);
 
  expect($result)->toBe(3);
})->only();
```

See the [docs](https://pestphp.com/docs/filtering-tests#content-only)